# HTTP 415 when I add a string array as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am working on an API where I want to provide the user an option to pass a list of IDs in addition to another string parameter.

This works:

```cs
[HttpGet("{category}")]
public IEnumerable<Product> Get(string category)
{
    return _databaseService.GetProductsCollection(category)
                           .Find(_ => true)
                           .ToEnumerable();
}
```

But if I add a `string[]`/`IEnumerable<string>`/`IList<string>`/`List<string>` for productIds to this method, it stops working and I get an HTTP 415 as below.

```cs
[HttpGet("{category}")]
public IEnumerable<Product> Get(string category, string[] productIds)
{
    return _databaseService.GetProductsCollection(category)
                           .Find(_ => true)
                           .ToEnumerable();
}
```

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "00-0a39fd26ca04564a8897c03898b98c64-cfbf424ec3163344-00"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried searching the web but I haven't found anything relevant. I'm trying to use a URL formatted as `api/products/electronics?productIds=45A&productIds=72C`. I cannot use something like `productIds=45A,72C` and then do a split with comma since my method then clashes with another route on the same resource (`{category}/{productId}`) to fetch a specific product.

I'm using ASP.NET Core on .NET 5.0. Not sure if it's the .NET version causing issues or it's something else.

Please feel free to let me know if you have any additional advice as well!

Comment: Try using the `[FromQuery]` attribute, with explicit name like this. `[FromQuery(Name="productIds")]`. It should work. I haven't tested this tough.

Comment: Yup, this worked! Thank you! Is there any good reference for these attributes regarding this? I have been going through the official documentation but I find it a bit confusing to understand how they are making use of the Route and other attributes.

Comment: Actually, I got to know that from experience. However, you can follow this link to read more about model binding in Asp.Net Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll take a look. You could perhaps answer the question with it so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Great. I added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `[FromQuery]` attribute, with explicit name like this: `[FromQuery(Name="productIds")]`.
It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize your input to a JSON string, and send that string to the API. With this approach you can receive a string in your API which you can deserialize (e.g. with Newtonsoft JSON).

Comment: While this would work, it feels like a workaround. Typically JSON strings would be sent over POST and PUT. This one is a GET. I've also seen APIs that work with this. I believe there should be a way to address this the way I'm trying to.

Comment: What if you annotate your string[] productIds parameter in the API with the [FromQuery] attribute?

Comment: Yeah, that did it!